# Is it possible to delete a user profile only on the meta site?

Tags: support, faq, user-profiles

Can users delete their user profile on a meta site and keep it on the parent site?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't; there's no [delete tab on your Meta profile](/users/delete/current) like there is [on the main site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current).

What *would* work is to delete your main profile (given that you have some contributions, this may not be instantaneous), and recreate it afterwards and be careful that you don't visit Drupal Meta (while logged in). Your meta profile is only created upon your first visit there.